# Does anyone have an example repository that uses Cucumber/Gherkin with Allure Reports for Java/Groovy-based Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, cucumber, allure

I have a simple CalculatorTest where I would like to generate test results in a folder when the test is run and then run Allure Serve on it to create the Allure report.  I am not sure how to configure CucumberOptions in the TestRunner class and what I actually need for plugins, etc., in the build.gradle file.

I have the following groovy code and know the plugin is incorrect since the class is not found.

I would love to see an actual working example of how to configure the project that uses Allure 2.  Currently, I am not sure I am headed down the correct path.  Thanks so much.  (Note:  The test runs successfully in IntelliJ but the reports are not output to the build/allure-results folder. )

Here's my CalculatorTest.groovy file:

```
package TestRunner

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true,
        strict = true,
        plugin = ["pretty", "io.qameta.allure.cucumber2jvm.AllureCucumber2Jvm"],
        glue = ["Steps"],
        features = ["src/main/groovy/feature/calculator.feature"])

class CalculatorTest {

}
```

Here's the calculator.feature file:

```
Feature: Calculator

  Scenario: Adding two numbers
    Given I have a calculator
    When I add 1 and 2
    Then  I should get 3
```

Here is the sdCalculator.groovy file:

```
package Steps

this.metaClass.mixin(cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks)
this.metaClass.mixin(cucumber.api.groovy.EN)


    Calculator calculator
    Integer result

    Given(/I have a calculator/)
            { ->
                calculator = new Calculator();
            }

    When(/I add {int} and {int}/)
            { Integer a, Integer b ->
                result = calculator.add(a, b)
            }

    Then(/I should get {int}/) { Integer c ->
        assert(result).equals(c)
    }
```

And the Calculator class:

```
package Steps

public class Calculator {
    public Integer add(Integer a, Integer b){
        return a + b
    }
}
```

I have a config/cucumber.yml file that contains:

```
default: "--format pretty --format AllureCucumber::CucumberFormatter --out build/allure-results"
```

And an allure.properties that contains:

```
allure.results.directory=build/allure-results
allure.link.issue.pattern=https://example.org/browse/{}
allure.link.tms.pattern=https://example.org/browse/{}
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase the subject and add the error you get? You already tried some things and it did not work, but as the question is phrased it might just be closed, because it looks for a tutorial. Turn it into a question about the error or problem you face.

Comment: I was looking for an example repo that used the plugin.  I get a "Couldn't load plugin class" error.  Adding a task to the gradle file that contains the plugin as an arg, (which does not use the TestRunnerCucumber, but uses cucumber.api.cli.Main directly), and then using that task to execute the tests, solves the problem.